# XSLT Iterations over

Tags: xslt, foreach

I am getting an error that says that my template total-seconds-calculation does not exist. Am I doing something wrong with the for-each loop that is throwing the error at me?

My current code is:

```
<xsl:template match="Total-Seconds-Calculation">

    <xsl:for-each select="//SEGMENTS[TX_PART = '1']">
        <xsl:value-of select="DUR"/> 
        <xsl:variable name="Hours" select="substring($DUR,1,2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="Minutes" select="substring($DUR,4,2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="Seconds" select="substring($DUR,7,2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="TotalSeconds" select="(($Hours*3600)+($Minutes*60)+($Seconds))" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="TotalDurationShow"><xsl:call-template name="Total-Seconds-Calculation"></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
```

What I am trying to do is parse this time code and add up the total seconds of DUR. Here is the portion of the XML that I am using:

```
<SEGEMENTS>
    <DUR>00:12:33:21</DUR>
    <TX_PART>1</TX_PART>
</SEGEMENTS>
<SEGEMENTS>>
    <DUR>00:08:26:16</DUR>
    <TX_PART>1</TX_PART>
</SEGEMENTS>
```

Comment: What does the error message say, exactly?  And what are you trying to do with this code?  In particular, why are you declaring variables you never use  or refer to?

Comment: @C. M. Sperberg-McQueen The error message was giving me an invalid template, now the template is just not creating any out put. The variables are declared to compute the last variable TotalSeconds which is clearly in the template.

Comment: It appears that the question you asked (why does it say my template does not exist?) has been answered.  You should accept bjimba's answer, and if you have new questions (such as:  why does this code not do what I want it to do?) you may wish to raise them in separate questions.  Or you might want to read up on variable scopes in XSLT, and think about the fact that XSLT does not have mutation: it's an assign-once language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the template by name, you have to name it.

```
<xsl:template name="Total-Seconds-Calculation">
```

You can have both a `name` attribute and a `match` attribute if you want, although I've never found a good use for that.